# hibernate::map mapping

Tags: hibernate, dictionary

I have some class **C** that contains *Map<**A**, Set<**B**>>*, where **A** and **B** has *long id* and mapped in tables *a* and *b*. I want do some mapping of **C** into table with 2 attributes a_id and b_id. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not positive I understood you question correctly, but if I did you could try the following.

Create a new table that has 3 columns, a_id, b_id, and c_id where only c_id cannot be null. Every entry in that table will represent a mapping from c -> {a || b}. In hibernate you will have a ManyToMany set or list of a's and b's in the c class.

Comment: Ooops! There is some error. I'm meaning, Map<A, Set<B>> instead  Map<A, B>. And I couldn't write .hbm.xml for it(